# IntlDateFormatter::getPattern returns a wrong pattern

Tags: php, datetime, internationalization

I'm formatting `DateTime` (`Carbon\Carbon`) dates with `IntlDateFormatter`.
However, the pattern does not match the formatted date in every case. I noticed that with German settings:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-06-27');
$locale = 'de';
$timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';

$datetype = IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM;
$timetype = IntlDateFormatter::NONE;

$intlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, $datetype, $timetype, $timezone);

$pattern = $intlDateFormatter->getPattern();

$date = $intlDateFormatter->format($datetime);
```

`$date` returns correctly `27.06.2016`. But `$pattern` returns `dd.MM.y`.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just found out that the patterns returned are no php but CLDR patterns. Those date patterns are described [here](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time-patterns).
Next step: searching for the best way to convert CLDR patterns to php patterns.

Comment: The [Punic library](http://punic.github.io/) has a method, [Punic\Calendar::tryConvertIsoToPhpFormat()](http://punic.github.io/docs/source-class-Punic.Calendar.html#234), for converting CLDR patterns to PHP patterns.However, not all CLDR symbols are supported by PHP, so you may be better off using Intl or Punic to do the actual formatting rather than PHP's built-in formats.